# What hoster offers automatic Wordpress upgrades (like Dreamhost) and _also_ spreads your sites over range of unique IP addresses?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, wordpress, ip-address, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I just love the One-click-install and automatic Wordpress upgrades at Dreamhost.

However, I am looking for a hoster where I can be sure that my sites end up with different IP addresses (for SEO reasons).  Dreamhost does not offer that option, you have to buy unique IP-addresses for every site if you want to do so, which is expensive.  I do not care that it is shared hosting, meaning that my sites share the same IP address with other sites, as long as they're not on the same IP themselves (and yes, preferable not within the same IP range).

Do you know of a hoster who offers the Wordpress managing comfort of Dreamhost yet lets you spreads your sites over multiple IPs?

(note: inspired by a similar discussion at this Dreamhost forum: http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-129719.html

Comment: Isn't the whole different-IPs-are-good-for-SEO thing a [complete and total myth](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/myth-busting-virtual-hosts-vs-dedicated-ip-addresses/)?  Or are you trying to [game the system](http://hostingfu.com/article/hosting-more-ip-addresses-seo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SEO Hosting](http://www.seohosting.com/hosting-plans.php) (from [Hostgator](http://hostgator.com)) offer shared plans designed to run sites from multiple IP addresses, including Fantastico support, which allows you to install WordPress. They start at $35/month, so it may prove cheaper and more convenient to pay for multiple IPs from your existing host.

Note also that gaming search engines by building link farms and/or tricking them into believing that you don't own multiple cross-linked sites is prone to risk should search engines start blacklisting or penalising IPs from known 'SEO webhosts'.

Blackhat SEO techniques, whilst interesting technically, are rarely a worthwhile substitute for building great content that people will love, use, and spread on your behalf without subterfuge.